# max value in insert into

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the maximum number in a column because in a insert operation I have to insert max number in that column +1 for each insert, I did this:

```
insert into table1(id ,.., field,...)
select newid(), ..., (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), FORMAT((MAX(number)+1),'00000000'))
   FROM table1)
```

It works just for the first inserted row, than I get this number for other rows too!

Comment: *"I have to insert max number in that column +1"* Don't. Use an `IDENTITY` column. If you *must* then have sequential values, use a `VIEW` and `ROW_NUMBER`. Let SQL Server gracefully handle the incrementing value. Trying to increment the number yourself is going to only cause you problems, such as race conditions, and your data will be in a far worse position.

Comment: That is a really, really bad idea, don't do it. This won't work properly if you have concurrent transactions doing the same thing.

Comment: this is the db I have and I can't change it, I just have to insert some data so I can't use identity

Comment: Then i suggest you feedback to whomever can, @marko . This design is fundamentally flawed and you **will** end up with invalid data; it's just a matter of time. Fix the problem now, before it becomes a much larger problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Why aren't you using an identity column?  You can define the number as:

```
number int identity(1, 1)
```

If you want the value as a string padded to eight characters, then use a computed column:

```
number_string as (format(number, '00000000'))
```

EDIT:

There are strong reasons why you want an `identity` column and not to calculate the values yourself.  You can do what you want using `row_number()`, where the logic looks like this:

```
insert into table1(id ,.., field,...)
    select newid(), ...,
           convert(varchar(8),
                   (coalesce(t1.max_number, 0) + 
                    row_number() over (order by (select null))
                   )
                  )
     from table2 t2 cross join
          (select max(t1.number) as max_number from table1 t1) t1;

N
```

Note:  I am assuming that the inserts are coming from a different table, but `table2` can really be `table1`.

Very importantly:  **This is not thread safe.**  Two different threads can run the same code and result in the same values.  The solution to this is locking the entire table.  However, that can have very significant performance impacts.

Comment: Probably want to add `PERSISTED` to that computed column. `FORMAT`is an awfully slow function, so if you are using it in a computed column, at least store the value rather than giving SQL Server the (huge) overhead later when you go to read said data.

Comment: this is the db I have and I can't change it, I just have to insert some data so I can't use identity

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to comment on here, and like Gordon, I can't fit it into one.

Firstly, I notice you have a column `id` and you're inserted the value `NEWID()` into it. I therefore *hope* that `id` isn't your `CLUSTERED INDEX`, as if it is `NEWID()` is not doing it any favours. If you are using a `uniqueindentifier` for your `CLUSTERED INDEX`, use `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` instead, and don't provuide the value in the `INSERT`:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Table1_id DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() FOR id;
```

As for your `INSERT`, as I said in my comment: *"Use an `IDENTITY` column. If you **must** then have sequential values, use a `VIEW` and `ROW_NUMBER`. Let SQL Server gracefully handle the incrementing value. Trying to increment the number yourself is going to only cause you problems, such as race conditions, and your data will be in a far worse position."*. Unfortunately you can't change an existing column to an `IDENTITY`, so this is a little harder. Likely you'll want to do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD number_new int IDENTITY(1,1);
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Table1 ON;
--UPdate the new column with the existing values
UPDATE dbo.Table1
SET number_new = number;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Table1 OFF;
GO
--Drop the old column and rename
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 DROP COLUMN number;
EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.Table1.number_new', N'number', N'COLUMN'
```

As Gordon said, if you simply then need a formatted value (with leading 0's) and no worry about gaps, use a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD Number_f AS RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000',number),8) PERSISTED;
```

If, however, you want them to be in sequential order, and update accordingly when a row is deleted, or a `INSERT` fails, etc, then you can use a view, with the following expression:

```
RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000',ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number ASC),8)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `ROW_NUMBER()` function to increment the IDs.  Just replace the `+1` with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`.  Something like this:

```sql
insert into table1(id ,.., field,...)
select (SELECT MAX(number) FROM table1) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY <field1>), ...
from table1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6669a/13)

Comment: This is just a bad idea, as per the comment from myself under the question.

Comment: I'm not saying it's good or bad...I'm just answering the guy's question :)  I agree, an `identity` column is the way to go.

Comment: @ravioli I still get the same number for each inserted row

Comment: I updated the answer.  Can you please post the exact query you ran?