# How does cross join work with row_number() over?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, row-number

I don't have an identity (auto-increment) property over my `record_id` column, but a sequence instead. I needed to copy whole bunch of data (all rows) into a history table. The problem here is that there are conflicts as to per table's record ids. That is, when I want to `insert into select from blahblah`, history table's sequence is already there. To handle this case, row_number over solution I tried to find and @Gordon Linoff wrote [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58484361) which I rewrite again with some alterations. When I run the code from top to bottom once, and equally sequentially subsequently from `INSERT INTO #a (a,aa) SELECT  ...`  to bottom, it puts by 5, as expected. What I want to learn with your precious instructions and educative approaches that

- Why does he use `t1`s before the closing parentheses and after? `(select max(a) as max_number from #a t1) t1`. I know before the closing parentheses, it may be not used. But it was. The cases you encountered, or logically reasons.
- We can satisfy my desire by rewriting as following `coalesce((select max(a) as max_number from #a), 0) +  row_number() over (order by (select null))` but he did prefer to use `cross join`. Even though I'm really happy to use first time cross join in reality, I feel a dummy man myself since I don't understand the steps, to be frank, I can't figure out **how(and)why** cross join and aforementioned `t1`s' usages are used.
- Why is `order by` used by `select null` instead of a column?

Would you mind please explaining step-by-step?

```sql
CREATE TABLE #a
(
    a INT PRIMARY KEY,
    aa int
)

CREATE TABLE #b
(
    b int
)

-- 1,3,5 is not typical. Just to test. Of course in my db, they are subsequent.
INSERT INTO #a VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO #a VALUES(3,1);
INSERT INTO #a VALUES(5,1);

INSERT INTO #b VALUES(12);
INSERT INTO #b VALUES(23);
INSERT INTO #b VALUES(33);
INSERT INTO #b VALUES(43);
INSERT INTO #b VALUES(53);

INSERT INTO #a
(a,aa)
SELECT  (coalesce(t1.max_number, 0) + 
        row_number() over (order by (select null))), b 
        from #b 
        cross join (select max(a) as max_number from #a t1) t1  
select * from #a
```

Comment: `t1` is an alias. `t1) t1 ` are 2 aliases, one within the inner query's scope, the latter the outer query's.

Comment: IN regards to the `ORDER BY`, because `ROW_NUMBER` requires an `ORDER BY` clause in its `OVER`, but presumably it';s wanted that ordering of those values is completely arbitrary; `SELECT NULL` achieves that.

Comment: There are 3 records in `#a`, and 5 in `#b`. Selecting all records from `#b` results in 5 records, because the CROSS JOIN does not add records, it only influences the values returned.  These 5 records are INSERTed in `#a`, resulting in (5+3=) 8 records.

Comment: A cross join to a sub-query with one row will be exactly the same as a `join on X=x` except quicker because it doesn't test any thing.

Comment: (Edit) Usually a cross join is used to deliberately generate a set of all possible combinations of data from multiple tables. (That's obviously not the case here since the subquery only returns a single row.) IMO it's used for readability, to clearly indicate there's no direct relationship between `#b` and the subquery.